# Issue with $route in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have been writing an electron app with angularJs. I am using the $route to switch between views but my views dont show up. i have been trying to fix it for 4 hours.please can anyone help?.here is my project files.Thank you in advance

https://mega.nz/#!Rlg1HY5a!d2hr0pXtIqF3YgzXOu3FLy8b-YIwMgLptZOiuufQnuQ

Comment: You should post your code here, not the link for download the whole project.

Comment: the modules and controllers and different views are quite a lot.

Comment: I checked your site but didn't see any issue. Did you fix it or were you trying to get a SEO link to your site?

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: @Rejs i did that and my entire ui doesnt work.i cannot even right click to open dev tools.and it never finishes loading. here is a snap shot https://i.imgsafe.org/4580438812.png